# Clang undefined behavior checker link error

Tags: c++, macos, clang

Upon trying to compile a C++ source file with clang 3.5 with the undefined behavior checker

```
 clang++-3.5 -std=c++11 -fsanitize=undefined main.cpp
```

I am getting the following error upon linking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      __ubsan::checkDynamicType(void*, void*, unsigned long) in libclang_rt.ubsan_osx.a(ubsan_type_hash.o)
      isDerivedFromAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long) in libclang_rt.ubsan_osx.a(ubsan_type_hash.o)
      findBaseAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long) in libclang_rt.ubsan_osx.a(ubsan_type_hash.o)
  "typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      isDerivedFromAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long) in libclang_rt.ubsan_osx.a(ubsan_type_hash.o)
      findBaseAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long) in libclang_rt.ubsan_osx.a(ubsan_type_hash.o)
  "typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:
      isDerivedFromAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long) in libclang_rt.ubsan_osx.a(ubsan_type_hash.o)
      findBaseAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long) in libclang_rt.ubsan_osx.a(ubsan_type_hash.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Do I need to link with an additional library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing `libc++abi`. Try adding

```
-lc++abi
```

to your link command.